# Accepting arguments for settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, arguments

Hello I’m in the process of writing a command line program and am struggling with accepting arguments.

I have got the application working where they can type in the program and the data I.e.

```
CMD>software (name)
```

I’m just not sure how to get it where they can configure settings for example change the server using the command –s . I need to get the application to work something like this:

```
CMD>software –s 192.168.1.1 (name)

CMD>software (name) -s 192.168.1.1
```

I know how to actually change the server etc. just not sure how to accept these settings using the arguments.

Comment: How does your Main method declaration look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make your `Main` method accept a string array:

```
public class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
test.exe foo bar baz

0: foo
1: bar
2: baz
```

Note that unlike some other languages, `args[0]` is *not* the name of the binary - it really is the first *argument* to the binary.

There are third-party libraries to help turn a sequence of command line arguments into more useful settings. For example, in Noda Time we embed [this one](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I’m sorry to ask daft questions but how do I get the information from the for loop into strings.

Comment: @Idiot: What do you mean? They're already *in* strings (in the `args` array). You could use `string firstArg = args[0];` if you really want...

Comment: Sorry I forget there in the string array from the main method declaration but I’m still not sure what to put in the for loop??

Comment: @Idiot: I'm not sure how to answer you from here. I've given you the information about how to get the strings that the user put on the command line. How you then *handle* those strings is a separate issue - although you should follow the link in the bottom paragraph of my answer for one (of many) third party library for parsing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I’m sorry I should have been clearer. 

I currently have a switch statement which checks the length of the array and then depending on the length been 1 or 2 does the following: 

`case 1: string 1 = args[0];`

`case2: string 1 = args[0]; and string 2 = args[1];`
 
The problem I’m having is they may not enter the settings and not necessarily in the same order and really not sure how to mange the various lengths?

Comment: @Idiot: Well did you follow my suggestion of looking into a third party library? At this point we're quite a long way from your original question of how you get the command line arguments into your app - it's more about how you *parse* them.

Comment: Sorry I dint know what it was called. I dont think i'm allowed to use third party library's as its part of my coursework.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do chat at the moment. I think you may be best off asking a separate question though.

Comment: Thanks I just clicked on the: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" I wondered what it was.